# Changing CSS On Scroll With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a header that becomes smaller once a user scrolls on my site. The logo and header part is done, but when I try to resize the text for the navigation, something becomes broken and the header no longer shrinks on scroll. Here is my broken code with the text resize: (#HOME is the ID for styles associated with a navigation link):

```
$(function() {
$('#Header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
    if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'big') {
        $('#Header').data('size', 'small');
        $('#Header').stop().animate({
            height: '60px'
        }, 600);
        $('#Logo').stop().animate({
            height: '40px',
            width: '40px'
        },600);
        $('#Logo:hover').stop().animate({
            height: '40px',
            width: '40px'
        },600);
        $('#HOME').stop().animate({
            font-size: '14px',
            top: '20px'
        },600);
    }
} else {
    if ($('#Header').data('size') == 'small') {
        $('#Header').data('size', 'big');
        $('#Header').stop().animate({
            height: '100px'
        }, 600);
        $('#Logo').stop().animate({
            height: '85px',
            width: '81px'
        },600);
        $('#Logo:hover').stop().animate({
            height: '40px',
            width: '40px'
        },600);
        $('#HOME').stop().animate({
            font-size: '17px',
            top: '40px'
        },600);
    }  
}
});
```

The code works without the #HOME additions to the *if* and *else*.

Comment: FYI, if you catch yourself using the same jQuery selector more than once, you should pull it out of your chain and make it a variable first. That way you're not requerying the DOM every single type you reference it.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle with some sample HTML, I'll take a look at your problem.

Comment: Mario, you can view the site here: http://tremor.yt/Site/Creators.html